# How to use Select html tag in thyemeleaf?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I am going to add a select tag into my theyemeleaf application. Below is the code:

```html
<form th:action="@{/suggestevent}" th:object="${event}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="type" th:field="*{type}">
            <option value="party" th:value="party">Party</option>
            <option value="Workshop" th:value="Workshop">Workshop</option>
            <option value="Friendship" th:value="Friendship">Friendship</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have only three fix values in my dropbox. The issue is it does not set any value into the attribute `type`.
in other word, it does not work.

Comment: Can you provide more info? Like your model and the controller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **th:selected** attributes like below.And if you use the **th:selected** approach you should not use the **th:field** one. So try removing the **th:field** attribute.

```
<form th:action="@{/suggestevent}" th:object="${event}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="type">
            <option value="party" th:value="party" th:selected="(${event.type}== 'party')">Party</option>
            <option value="Workshop" th:value="Workshop" th:selected="(${event.type} == 'Workshop')">Workshop</option>
            <option value="Friendship" th:value="Friendship" th:selected="(${event.type} == 'Friendship')">Friendship</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use thymeleaf and their attributes, is easier than expected, then just use th:field and th:value, those 2 attributes will add by default the attribute name and value, so you dont need to add it.

```
<form th:action="@{/suggestevent}" th:object="${event}"  method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{type}">
            <option th:value="party">Party</option>
            <option th:value="Workshop">Workshop</option>
            <option th:value="Friendship">Friendship</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```